# Cant redeem Google Play promo code, getting "redeem Error code: BM-BQ-01"

Tags: android, google-play, promotion-code

I am working on an App that has a premium subscription (as in-app purchase).

we have released it to Google alpha channel and we had given a close group of testers promo codes to test it.

The problem is that when they are trying to redeem the promo code given to them they are getting

```
Error redeeming code. Error code: BM-BQ-01
```

when I tried on my phone it works great but for the testers, it's showing that error.

**Tried solutions:**

- Pay settings set to the same country as Play store
- clear Play store data and cache

Any help will be appreciated

[image: BM-BQ-01 ScreenShoot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently in order to redeem a promo code associated with an app you need to have the app installed first in the device.

I would never guest it from `"BM-BQ-01"`.